# DefaultHttpClient#execute freezes sometimes when requesting host from VM

Tags: java, virtualbox, apache-httpclient-4.x

**Goal:** Request a web service from a virtual machine

**Trouble:** Feeze on `httpClient.execute(request)`

**Environment:**

- **Host:** Window Server 2008 R2 x64

  - VirtualBox 4.2.16
  - IIS 6.1
- **2x VM:** Kubuntu 12.04.2 amd64
  network setting: NAT + port forwarding

  - Apache tomcat 7.0.26
  - JVM 1.6

So, the web service comes from [M-Files](http://mfiles.com/en/), a document management system, and runs on IIS. Obviously, my web application runs on tomcat. There are two virtual machine

How I initialize the `HttpClient`:

```java
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(1000));
```

I have setted the timeout parameter to ensure the application doesn't freeze when `execute` freezes.

How I create a request:

```java
private HttpGet createHttpGet(String url, boolean isAuthenticate) throws IOException {
  HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
  if (isAuthenticate)
    get.addHeader("X-Authentication", getAuthenticationToken());
  return get;
}
```

How I execute a request:

```java
private String executeAndReturn(HttpRequestBase request) throws IOException {
  logger.info("[MFiles: request] " + request.getURI());
  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
  logger.info("[MFiles] request sent, waiting response");

  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
  String tmp;
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  while ((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    logger.info("[MFiles] reading response");
    builder.append(tmp);
  }
  tmp = builder.toString();
  reader.close();

  logger.info("[MFiles: response] " + tmp);
  return tmp;
}
```

I am able to reach the host from the virtual machine with `ping 10.0.2.2` or `ping 192.168.56.102` and request the web service on `http://10.0.2.2/REST` or `http://192.168.56.102/REST` but some request freeze, and I don't understand why. Moreover if I deploy my web app on the host, all is alright !
I have suspected a mistake in my VM network configuration, but in this case it should never succesfully runs, shouldn't it ?

Any help appreciate :)